# Grunt kill watch session & use variables in grunt file names

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and this sublime package [sublime-grunt](https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt).

1. I am using the sublime-grunt package to start a watch session and livereload with the Chrome extension. Everything works great however once a 'watch' session is started what is the command to stop/kill/cancel a watch. I tried using a command in the sublime-grunt package called 'Grunt Kill Running Processes' and it tells me something has been canceled but if I change my style.scss file and save it, it compiles and updates are made to my html page, so 'watch' is still in effect. Right now I have to close down Sublime Text to kill the 'watch' session.
2. I am trying to use a variable for a path to my theme root directory but when  I try to concat the variable with a string I received this error. What type of syntax should I use, do I need to create a variable in the package.json file?

Code

```
    var theme_path  = 'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/';

    // Sass plugin
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                theme_path + 'style.css': theme_path + 'sass/style.scss',
            }
        }
    },

    // Error
    Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> SyntaxError: C:\wamp\www\grunt\Gruntfile.js:31
    >>                                      theme_path + 'style.css': 'wp-content/th
    emes/twentyfifteen/sass/style.scs
    >>                                                 ^
    >> Unexpected token +
    Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Theme Directory Path
    var theme_path  = 'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/';

    // Configure main project settings
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Basic settings and info about our plugins
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // Watch Plugin
        watch: {
          sass: {
            files: 'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/sass/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass','postcss','uglify'],
            options: {
              livereload: true,
            },
          },
        },

        // Sass plugin
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css': 'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/sass/style.scss',
                }
            }
        },

        // Postcss plugin
        postcss: {
            options: {
              map: true, // inline sourcemaps

              // or
              map: {
                  inline: false, // save all sourcemaps as separate files...
              },

              processors: [
                require('pixrem')(), // add fallbacks for rem units
                require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}), // add vendor prefixes
                require('cssnano')() // minify the result
              ]
            },
            dist: {
              src: 'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css'
            }
        },

        // Minify JS Uglify
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.min.js': ['wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js']
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // Load the plugin
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    // Run plugin
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that tasks options can't have variable assigned, i don't have any source at the moment but i can suggest another way to do it:

you can use task params:

```
watch: {
    sass: {
        files: '<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/sass/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass:<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>','postcss','uglify'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
    },
},
sass: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/style.css': '<%= grunt.task.current.args[0] %>/sass/style.scss',
            }
        }
},
```

and than

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch:'+theme_path] );
```

This is a problem that i have already meet to make dynamic watch tasks